# How to make this code more well organized

Tags: php, logic, design-patterns

Here is the code... My if , else statement is very long... How to separate it? Any suggestion? Thank you.

```
public function receiveMsg(aMsg){
    if($aMsg instanceof LoginMsg){
         $this->callingSomeMethod();         //should I separate this code into other class/ object? 
         $this->callingAnotherMethod();  //should I separate this code into other class/ object? 

         $aMsg = new RespondLoginMsg();  //should I separate this code into other class/ object? 
         $this->sendMsg($aMsg);          //should I separate this code into other class/ object? 

    }else if(aMsg instanceof LogoutMsg){
         $this->callingSomeMethod();     //should I separate this code into another class/ object? 

         $aMsg = new RespondLogoutMsg();     //should I separate this code into another class/ object? 
         $this->sendMsg($aMsg);               //should I separate this code into another class/ object? 


    }else if/*****bababab***/

    /*****many else if here (up to 200 msg+ , just upload 2 here.)***/


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a switch is easier to read? And the sendMsg could be moved out of it either way and just use the $aMsg object that you set in the swtich/if..

```
$strMessageClass=get_class($aMsg);
switch ($strMessageClass) {
    case 'LoginMsg':
        $this->callingSomeMethod();
        $aMsg = new RespondLoginMsg();
    case 'RespondLogoutMsg':
        $this->callingAnotherMethod();
        $aMsg = RespondLogoutMsg();
    default:
        // If you have any..
}
$this->sendMsg($aMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything fundamentally wrong about a long if/else statement if that's what's called for.

If you're finding it to be an eyesore, why not just define the contents of each if/else block as it's own function?

You can also consider eliminating redundencies. If they all end with

```
     $aMsg = new RespondLoginMsg();
     $this->sendMsg($aMsg);
```

then there's no need to repeat it in each block.

Comment: no, as you can see, the second one is RespondLogoutMsg instead of RespondLoginMsg.....

Answer (score 0):

Other than getting rid of excessive spacing and line breaks I don't see what the problem here is. How many different classes do you need to check if an item is an instance of? Seems to me that the list would be pretty limited here. If you don't have any more than 3 or 4 if/else statements then just keep it an if/else. Otherwise use a switch or a loop.

Can you be more specific as to what your are trying to accomplish?

Here is a slightly cleaner version of your code.

```
public function receiveMsg(aMsg) {
  if ($aMsg instanceof LoginMsg) {
    $this->callingSomeMethod(); 
    $this->callingAnotherMethod();

    $aMsg = new RespondLoginMsg();
    $this->sendMsg($aMsg);
  }
  else if (aMsg instanceof LogoutMsg) {
    $this->callingSomeMethod(); 

    $aMsg = new RespondLogoutMsg();
    $this->sendMsg($aMsg);
  }
  else if { /*****bababab***/

  }
  /*****many else if here***/
}
```

Comment: I cut down the source code, I have up to 200 msg.... they work similar way, so, I just copy a few and post it here.

Comment: You have up to 200 different types of messages? Because I am talking about the types. And that would mean you have 200 different classes for this. That is excessive. You can probably just make one message class and create a function for each message type in the class. Then you could just create a loop that checks type and calls the appropriate function. This function will then make all the subcalls needed. That way you don't have to put it in this function. Keeps your code cleaner and more reusable.